# Allowing a Standard Plus user to execute APEX code from a button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a button that was created using the declarative interface. It sits on a page layout for a custom object. This button opens up a Visual Force page. Once this visual force pages loads, it runs some apex code and then returns back to the page the button was on. As an administrator, this works wonderfully. However for one of my users, who is a standard plus user, they are greeted with a message telling them that they have insufficient privileges.

I have tried the following to allow them access:

- Sharing Rules
- Permission Sets
- Security settings on the apex classes
- Remove 'with sharing' from one of the classes

My question is, what other ways does salesforce block access? Or what do I need to do to give this user sufficient privileges to run the apex code?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange, good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allow users to access the visualforce page. This can be done on profile level.

[image: Enable Visualforce]